# R: Assigning value to a matrix with variable name

Tags: r

I'm struggling to remove a row in a matrix, where this matrix's name is "unknown". What I mean by "unknown" is that there are several matrices, and the last 3 characters of each matrix's name is different.

An example would make this a lot clearer I think.

Say I have 3 matrices, Trades_ABC, Trades_DEF, Trades_HIJ. Each of these matrices has x rows and 5 columns.

I currently have the following code:
`for (k in 1:3)

assign(get(paste0("Trades_",sellLeg))[1,1],y)

next k`

Where "sellLeg" is one of "ABC","DEF","HIJ"

In this code I am trying to change the value of the first element in each of the three matrices to some number, represented by "1", as an example. In reality, I'm not so much looking to CHANGE a value as I am looking to REMOVE a row, but my main problem is that I don't know how to assign a value to a matrix with an "unknown" name (once I can do this I should be able to remove a row)

Many thanks!

Comment: Put them in a list and `<-` to `listname[[i]][1,1]`. (Don't use `assign`. It cannot handle teh combination of character names and function calls.

Comment: @DWin, thanks for the response. Do you mean I should put the matrices in a list, or the names of the matrix in a list? I've tried the following: `listName = ls(pat="Trades_") listName[[1]][1,1] = 1`, but I can't get it to work. The error reads `incorrect number of dimensions`, so I'm assuming it's treating the entry in the list as a string, not a matrix. Any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: Does `get(paste0("Trades_",sellLeg))[1,1] <- y` work?

Comment: just do like DWin said.

Comment: @Karl I thought what I did was what DWin had suggested? I put the variables in a list, and then  set listName[[i]][1,1] = 1

Comment: @geektrader, no, I had tried that previously as well

Comment: Take a look at your `listName` and you'll see all it contains is strings.  Read enough help files to understand what a `list` variable is.  Then, e.g., `for(j in 1:N) mylist[[j]]<-get(listName[j])` will create the object DWin is talking about.

Comment: yes, put the matrices inside the list, not the names.

Comment: Ok, awesome, thanks everybody, its working now! Much appreciated!@DWin, maybe you can put it as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks again!